# StreamCorruptedException при считывании шифрованного файла

Tags: java

**UPD:** Проблема решена. В методе `encrypt()` забыл закрыть поток записи объекта.

При попытке прочитать шифрованную строку в файле получаю

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 2C36A4CE
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:806)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at o26.controller.Decryptor.decrypt(Decryptor.java:34)
at o26.controller.Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

в строке

```
ois = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
```

Прикладываю весь код полностью. В нем, вроде как, ключ считывается из файла нормально. Что я делаю не так?

```
public class Encryptor {

    public static void encrypt(String secretFile, boolean appendFile, String secretString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        String algorithm = "DESede";

        File keyFile = new File("key.key");

        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey key = kg.generateKey();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(secretFile, appendFile), cipher));
        oos.writeObject(secretString);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(keyFile);
        fos.flush();

        String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded());
        fos.write(encodedKey.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
}

public class Decryptor {

    public static String decrypt(String secretFile) {

        FileReader reader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        String secretString = null;

        try {
            String keyFile = "key.key";
            String algorithm = "DESede";

            reader = new FileReader(keyFile);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String decodedKeyAsString = bufferedReader.readLine();

            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(decodedKeyAsString);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, algorithm);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(secretFile), cipher);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
            secretString = (String) ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка расшифровки!");
                }
            }
            if (ois != null) {
                try {
                    ois.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка расшифровки!");
                }
            }
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибка расшифровки!");
                }
            }
        }

        return secretString;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
        String test = "test";
        Encryptor.encrypt("secret", true, test);
        System.out.println(Decryptor.decrypt("secret"));

    }
}
```

Comment: функцию дописывания к файлу, наверное, надо убрать/переделать. У вас же каждый раз ключ меняется, поэтому предыдущие записи расшифровываются неправильно, и ObjectInputStream не может их прочесть.

Comment: и ObjectOutputStream не забудьте закрыть

Comment: @zRrr Точно. Я забыл закрыть поток. Спасибо большое.